# VIM :make compatible with plugins/vimrc

Tags: vim, plugins, makefile

I have been reading "Practical Vim" by Drew Neil over the last few weeks and found the tips very valuable. In Tip 104 about using the builtin `:make` command and the quickfix list, the book suggests opening the provided example file (see https://pragprog.com/titles/dnvim/source_code in `code/quickfix/wakeup`) via

```
vim -u NONE -N wakeup.c
```

and then invoking `:make` which works nicely.

However, in practice I would still like to make use of (g)vim together with my full `.vimrc` and all the plugins that I am using.
Opening the file via

```
vim wakeup.c
```

causes a series of errors of the type

```
wakeup.c:1:1: error: lexical error: illegal character \x{2f}
wakeup.c:1:4: error: syntax error: end of file expected, "*" found
wakeup.c:7:15: error: lexical error: illegal character \x{2f}
etc.
```

I have tried temporarily removing my local `.vimrc` file and `.vim` folder but I still get the errors.
What does this mean in practice? How can I get rid of the errors and use `:make` within the (g)vim environment that I am used to?

Comment: It means that you have syntastic installed. Uninstall it, disable it or change its options.

Comment: Or fix the source code `wakeup.c` so as to be compilable properly and other tools will not complain.